# "Him being a shepherd himself", is this correct?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Consider the following sentence:

> *{Foreign phrase}* means "the envy of all shepherds", him being a
> shepherd himself.

Does "him being a shepherd himself" sound natural?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  Omit **him being**. Prefer **....the envy of all shepherds, being a shepherd himself.**

Comment: After reading your comment below the answer below, I think you mean: As a shepherd, he is the envy of all other shepherds. Or just: He is the envy of all other shepherds. I hope no one deletes this comment like they deleted my other one.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is common in some dialects, for standard English the word "him" should be omitted.

There also needs someone for the "himself" to refer to.

For example

> He understood the sheepdog's strategy, being a shepherd himself.

Comment: Thank you. Does "being" in your example mean "because he is"?

Comment: Yes, it's pretty much exactly the same.

Comment: Actually when I said "him being a shepherd himself" I meant to add a clarification so the meaning of the phrase is perfectly clear. I was trying to say: "this phrase means that he (**a shepherd**) is the envy of all shepherds".    
Does "being a shepherd himself" deliver this meaning?